# subset df by masking between specific rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe, subset, mask

I'm trying to subset a pandas `df` by removing rows that fall between specific values. The problem is these values can be at different rows so I can't select fixed rows.

Specifically, I want to remove rows that fall between `ABC xxx` and the integer `5`. These values could fall anywhere in the `df` and be of unequal length.

Note: The string `ABC` will be followed by different values.

I thought about returning all the indexes that contain these two values.

But mask could work better if I could return all rows *between* these two values?

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Val' : ['None','ABC','None',1,2,3,4,5,'X',1,2,'ABC',1,4,5,'Y',1,2],                                                   
    })

mask = (df['Val'].str.contains(r'ABC(?!$)')) & (df['Val'] == 5)
```

Intended Output:

```
     Val
0   None
8      X
9      1
10     2
15     Y
16     1
17     2
```

Comment: Where did the `X`, `1` and `2` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ABC` is always before `5` and always pairs (`ABC`, `5`) get indices of values with `np.where`, `zip` and get index values between - last filter by `isin` with invert mask by `~`:

```
#2 values of ABC, 5 in data
df = pd.DataFrame({
   'Val' : ['None','ABC','None',1,2,3,4,5,'None','None','None',
            'None','ABC','None',1,2,3,4,5,'None','None','None']
    })

m1 = np.where(df['Val'].str.contains(r'ABC', na=False))[0]
m2 = np.where(df['Val'] == 5)[0]

print (m1)
[ 1 12]

print (m2)
[ 7 18]

idx = [x for y, z in zip(m1, m2) for x in range(y, z + 1)]
print (df[~df.index.isin(idx)])
     Val
0   None
8      X
9      1
10     2
11  None
19     X
20     1
21     2
```

Comment: 99% of the time there will always be one. But sometimes there will be 2. Never more than 2 though

Comment: @JPA0888 - Answer is edited, can you check with real data? If not working, what return `print (m1)` and `print (m2)` with real data?

Comment: I need it to handle one or two indices between those values.

Comment: @JPA0888 - yes, what return `print (m1)` and `print (m2)` ?

Comment: If I remove the concatenation it works great. Thanks @jezrael

Answer (score 1):

```
a = df.index[df['Val'].str.contains('ABC')==True][0]
b = df.index[df['Val']==5][0]+1
c = np.array(range (a,b))
bad_df = df.index.isin(c)
df[~bad_df]
```

**Output**

```
    Val
0   None
8   X
9   1
10  2
```

If there are more than one 'ABC' and 5, then you the below version.
With this you get the df other than the first `ABC` & the last `5`

```
a = (df['Val'].str.contains('ABC')==True).idxmax()
b = df['Val'].where(df['Val']==5).last_valid_index()+1
c = np.array(range (a,b))
bad_df = df.index.isin(c)
df[~bad_df]
```

Comment: I do not understand your question

Comment: if there are 2 ABC's  & 2 5's then this will give the values between the first ABC & the Last 5.

Comment: Yeh, apologies, I'll reframe the question. Its not between the first ABC and last 5. It's between sets of those values. So ABC and 5 could be on row 2 and 10. Another pair of those values could be on row 20 and 25. So I'd need to remove rows between 2-10 and 20-25. Does that make sense?

Comment: @JPA0888 - check my answer for solution.